# How to build Druapl 7 bilingual website?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

How I can build a bilingual version of my newly build website using Druapl 7.
I am using module Locale and entity_translation.When I clicking the arabic(my intention to support English,Arabic),that is not intending to RTL.
I have updated content type field  "Language" to "Language Neutral",how I can add the feature of bilingual in a manned which could change the language and indentation of each content?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The Internationalization (i18n) module is good, [Here](http://drupal.org/node/275705) is an excellent tutorial.

It's fairly robust, so I imagine it supports LTR script.